# Redirección de www a non www con https

Tags: apache, .htaccess, apache2

Tengo un problema con esto. El caso es que tengo un sitio con https, el cual se llama por ejemplo misitio. El caso es que si yo introduzco en el explorador la siguiente URL:
`https://www.misitio.es` me da error de certificado. Hace algún tiempo conseguí que funcionase. La dirección de la web es `https://misitio.es`. He conseguido que si introduzco la URL `http://www.misitio.es` me lleve a este, pero me está siendo imposible con https.
Mi contenido actual en htaccess es:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Pero al parecer no funciona. He probado bastantes cosas. ¿Estoy haciéndolo de forma correcta? O se me escapa algo. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Mas fácil: Agrega un alias al VirtualHost en puerto 443 `ServerAlias www.misitio.es`

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!!!! Después de las vueltas que he dado con esto.... Ya funciona como pretendía. Te lo agradezco de veras.